# Assembly x86 Delay loop

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, delay

hi i made program that will rotate two symbols - \ and / but i dont know how to set cx counter in nested loops can someone give me advice or help me ?

here is the code of that part

```
program:  
      mov ah, 0fh   ; function - get video mode
      int 10h
      push ax       ; save number of columns
      push bx       ; save page number
      mov ah, 0     ; function - set video mode
      int 10h

      mov al, 0003h     ;set video mode
      int 10h

      mov cx,10d  ; Outer loop counter how many symbols rotate

      mov bx,50d  ;   this is for delay loop
      OuterLoop:
      push cx

      mov ah,02h
      mov bh, 0        ;cursor set
      mov dh, 2
      mov dl, 10
      int 10h

      mov AH,0Ah
      mov al,"/"    symbol /
      mov bh,0
      mov cx,1
      int 10h

      mov cx,bx
      call Delay       ;delay loop
      sub bx,15d

      mov ah,02h
      mov bh, 0
      mov dh, 2            cursor set
      mov dl, 10
      int 10h

      mov AH,0Ah
      mov al,"\"             ;symbol \
      mov bh,0 
      mov cx,1
      int 10h


      mov cx,bx
      call Delay  ; another delay
      sub bx,10


      pop cx       ; Restore current CX
      loop OuterLoop

      jmp START     ; and after end it should jump to start where is menu with choices
```

it should work like this

write /
delay for example 10 sec
write \
delay 8 sec
and jump to beginning and loop

thanks for advices

this is my delay procedure

```
Delay   PROC    NEAR                    ;

    push    ds                      ;
    push    si                      ;
    push    ax                      ;
    xor     ax, ax                  ;AX = 0
    mov     ds, ax                  ;DS = 0
    mov     si, 046Ch               ;
t1:     mov     ax, [si]                ;
t2:     cmp     ax, [si]                ;
    je      t2                      ;
    loop    t1                      ;
    pop     ax                      ;
    pop     si                      ;
    pop     ds                      ;
    ret                             ;

Delay   ENDP                            ;
```

i am still working on this app but it is not working all i need is this steps to be made

program :  start of loop
            \
            delay       delay 100 times
            /
            delay       delay 80 times
           loop
 and after every loop to decrease delay like this 100 times 80,60,40 and so on but i dont know where to put push and pop cx because my delay procedure is working with cx. i just set cx for example to 100 and it makes delay and so on.

Comment: How precise do you want the Delay to be?  Does the program need to Delay the same amount in wall-clock time on processors with different CPU clock rates (GHz)?

Comment: no i dont want to precise delay like 5 seconds 4 and so on just delay. i want to write / than delay for example 10 seconds and then \ and delay 8 seconds and to loop that and decrease the amount of seconds i will post my delay procedure if you want

Comment: Sure, go ahead and post your Delay procedure.

Comment: i psoted it. i am trying to get it work whoel day but still no succes

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems:

First, `bx` is initialized here

```
mov bx,50d  ;   this is for delay loop
```

but then it gets over-written by

```
mov bh, 0
```

`bh` is bits 15:8 of `bx`

Second, in the Delay procedure, what modifies the location at `[si]` so that the `je t2` branch falls thru?  As it stands that is an infinite loop:

```
xor     ax, ax                  ;AX = 0
mov     ds, ax                  ;DS = 0
mov     si, 046Ch               ;
t1:     mov     ax, [si]        ;
t2:     cmp     ax, [si]        ;
        je      t2              ;
        loop    t1              ;
```

**Update:**
I found that address 0x46c is a BIOS address that contains time information.

http://www.osdata.com/system/physical/lowmem.htm

So the memory you are watching in that loop is a location updated by BIOS with a counter of timer ticks (counts every 54.9 milliseconds), see

http://code.google.com/p/xtideuniversalbios/source/browse/trunk/Assembly_Library/Src/Time/TimerTicks.asm?spec=svn131&r=131

So to answer your question, before calling your `Delay` procedure you should load `CX` with the count of BIOS ticks you wish to delay (time in milliseconds divided by 54.9).

Comment: i found that delay procedure on internet i dont know how it exactly works i just know that it works and thats all and it delay program when i set cx and i need to rewrite symbols at one position of cursor so \ rewrites / at first i wanted to use backspace but it was not working so my friend helped my with that instructions with set cursor and so on so i dont know how to replace them and avoid using that push

Comment: now i found out how to rewrite symbols without using push. i will use int 21h and i made a new delay loop

Comment: mov bh, 0 is not over-writing the value 50h moved into bx.  It's redundant or superfluous, but not harmful.  50h is stored in bits 7-0 of bx.  OTOH, there is no guarantee that int 10h will preserve the parameter values passed.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt, you are right, `BL` is bits 7:0 of `BX` so as long as the delay is less than 14 seconds then `BH` is zero.  When the desired delay is 14 seconds, that's 14,000 milliseconds and divided by 54.9 milliseconds/tick that's 255 ticks... which is the maximum that can be stored in the lower 8 bits of `BX`.

Answer (score 0):

For to drawing my own cursor i use the timer interrupt for to become a more steady delay on different performant CPUs.

```
Cursor_Speed = 7
;-------------DATA--------------------------------------
          CURFLAG DB 0, 0, 0, 0
          ALTVEC  DD 0
;-------------CODE--------------------------------------
          cli
          xor      ax, ax
          mov      es, ax
          mov      ebx, DWORD PTR es:[8*4] ; Get the old Vector (Offset/Segment)
          mov     DWORD PTR[ALTVEC], ebx   ; save it
          mov     cs:DWORD PTR[OLDVEC], ebx
          mov      es:[8*4], OFFSET NEWVEC ; Set the new IRQ-Vector
          mov      es:[(8*4)+2], cs

          mov      al, 36h                    ; Set 18,2 Hertz(Standard)
          out      43h, al
          xor      al, al
          out      40h, al           ; low
          out      40h, al           ; high
          sti
;---------------------------------------------------
          ......
;---------------------------------------------------
NEWVEC:   inc     BYTE PTR[CURFLAG+1]
          cmp     BYTE PTR[CURFLAG+1], Cursor_Speed
          jb  short NOHIT
          mov     BYTE PTR[CURFLAG+1], 0
          xor     BYTE PTR[CURFLAG], 1

NOHIT:    DB 0EAh                         ; jmp far
OLDVEC    DD 0
;---------------------------------------------------
```

....

Alternativly we can wait of the vsinc with polling port 3DAh for to become a little bit lesser precice delay.

Dirk